# IntelliJ command not found

Tags: bash, intellij-idea, pop-os

I have just installed IntelliJ Ultimate through the Pop!_OS shop. In the terminal there are commands missing which I have on the OS terminal.

Strange is also that $PATH has different content:

IntelliJ:

```
 /app/bin:/usr/bin:
```

Pop!_OS:

```
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

[image]

Do you know what is wrong in IntelliJ and do I have to change to have the same as in the OS?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the Flatpak version of IntelliJ IDEA. It runs in its own, semi-sandboxed environment. What you're seeing is by design.

To run JetBrains tools as usual you have to install them manually from their respective `.tar.gz` archives or using the JetBrains Toolbox program which doesn't require installation. The latter will also manage updates for you.

I think there's also a Snap version available which doesn't have the limitations of Flatpak, but you'd have to install `snapd` to run it. Snap will also auto-update programs for you. On Ubuntu which has Snap installed by default this could be the most convenient method, but Pop!_OS promotes Flatpak instead.